# How to add a ColorTween Animation to a TabBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm working on a simple Color Twin Animation between the Tabs

it should looking like this

[image]

i think i am near at a right solution, but when i tab on Tab3 nothing works fine

in each Tab i have a `Animation<color>` but i don't know how can i declare as a new one, or when i wipe to the new tab and set a new `ColorTween()`
Please help me, i don't know if i should create a new AnimationController or maybe only one `Animation<color>` for this 3 Tab's

here is some code of the Animation in the Tab

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setAnimation();

  }

  setAnimation() {

    if (widget.tabcontroller.animation.value == widget.tabindex ||
        widget.tabcontroller.animation.value + 1 == widget.tabindex ||
        widget.tabcontroller.animation.value - 1 == widget.tabindex) {

      // set animation in which direction
      animation = ColorTween(
        begin: widget.tabcontroller.animation.value == widget.tabindex ? new Color(0xff622F74) : Colors.black26,
        end: widget.tabcontroller.animation.value == widget.tabindex ? Colors.black26 : new Color(0xff622F74),
      ).animate(widget.tabcontroller.animation)
        ..addListener(() { setState(() {} ); });
    }

  }
```

and the full code

```
class TabAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabAnimationState createState() => _TabAnimationState();
}

class _TabAnimationState extends State<TabAnimation> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        accentColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("TabAnimatedColorTween"),
            bottom: new PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size(double.infinity, 48.0),
              child : new Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: new TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.black87,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: <Widget>[
                    Tab(child: new _Tab(0, "Tab1", _tabController)),
                    Tab(child: new _Tab(1, "Tab2", _tabController)),
                    Tab(child: new _Tab(2, "Tab3", _tabController)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(child: Center(child: new Text("1"))),
              new Container(child: Center(child: new Text("2"))),
              new Container(child: Center(child: new Text("3"))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class _Tab extends StatefulWidget {
  final int tabindex;
  final String tabname;
  final TabController tabcontroller;

  _Tab(this.tabindex, this.tabname, this.tabcontroller, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  __TabState createState() => __TabState();
}

class __TabState extends State<_Tab> {

  int count;
  Animation<Color> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setAnimation();

  }

  setAnimation() {

    if (widget.tabcontroller.animation.value == widget.tabindex ||
        widget.tabcontroller.animation.value + 1 == widget.tabindex ||
        widget.tabcontroller.animation.value - 1 == widget.tabindex) {

      // set animation in which direction
      animation = ColorTween(
        begin: widget.tabcontroller.animation.value == widget.tabindex ? new Color(0xff622F74) : Colors.black26,
        end: widget.tabcontroller.animation.value == widget.tabindex ? Colors.black26 : new Color(0xff622F74),
      ).animate(widget.tabcontroller.animation)
        ..addListener(() { setState(() {} ); });
    }

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(widget.tabname),
        new Container(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 22.0, minWidth: 22.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
          child: new Text(widget.tabindex.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 10.0),),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: animation == null ? Colors.black26 : animation.value,
              border: new Border.all(
                width: 0.8,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              boxShadow: [
                new BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                ),
              ]
          ),
        )
      ],
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve this problem

i did not add a new Animation to the TabBar. 
i work with the Animation.value in the tabcontroller

Color value get in the Tab

```
color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(getCurrClr()),
```

Opacity value from the tabController and current tab

```
double getCurrClr() {

    if(tabindex==0 && tabcontroller.animation.value < 1)
      return 1 - tabcontroller.animation.value;

    if(tabindex==1 && tabcontroller.animation.value <= 1)
      return tabcontroller.animation.value;

    if(tabindex==1 && tabcontroller.animation.value > 1)
      return 2 - tabcontroller.animation.value;

    if(tabindex==2 && tabcontroller.animation.value <= 2 && tabcontroller.animation.value > 1)
      return tabcontroller.animation.value - 1;

    return 0.0;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your solution [FloW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13055261/flow)

Here is an improvement on your `getCurrClr()` function:

```
// returns opacity [0.0 .. 1.0] for a tab using animation value and tab index
double getCurrClr() {
  final value = tabcontroller.animation!.value;
  
  if (tabindex == 0 && value < 1) {
    return 1 - value;
  } else if (value <= tabindex && value > tabindex - 1) {
    return value - (tabindex - 1);
  } else if (value > tabindex && value < tabindex + 1) {
    return (tabindex + 1) - value;
  }
  
  return 0.0;
}
```

This will work on any number of tabs whether there are three tabs or 15.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PyWidgetTestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  PyWidgetTestPage({Key key, routerArguments}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PyWidgetTestPageState createState() => _PyWidgetTestPageState();
}

class _PyWidgetTestPageState extends State<PyWidgetTestPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller; //= TabController(length: 14, vsync: this);
  AnimationController anicontroller;
  Animation animation;
  Animation<int> intAnim;
  Animation<Color> colorAni;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: 14, vsync: this);
    ;
    // ColorTween(
    // //   begin: Colors.black26,
    // //   end: new Color(0xff622F74),
    // // ).animate(_conrtoller)
    // //   ..addListener(() {
    // //     print("set stats");
    // //     setState(() {});
    // //   });
    // // _conrtoller.forward();
    // anicontroller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10000), vsync: this);
    // anicontroller.addListener(() {
    //   print("controller=====${anicontroller.value}");
    // });
    // anicontroller.addStatusListener((status) {
    //   print("status====$status");
    // });
    // intAnim = IntTween(begin: 0, end: 200).animate(anicontroller)
    //   ..addListener(() {
    //     setState(() {});
    //   })
    //   ..addStatusListener((status) {});
    // // colorAni = ColorTween(begin: Colors.purpleAccent, end: Colors.orange).animate(anicontroller)
    // //   ..addListener(() {
    // //     setState(() {});
    // //   })
    // //   ..addStatusListener((status) {});
    // anicontroller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return Scaffold(
    //   appBar: new AppBar(
    //     backgroundColor: colorAni?.value ?? Colors.purple,
    //     title: new Text("adfadf"),
    //   ),
    //   body: Column(children: [
    //     Text("${intAnim?.value ?? "ssss"}"),
    //   ]),
    // );
    return TabAnimation();
  }
}

class TabAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabAnimationState createState() => _TabAnimationState();
}

class _TabAnimationState extends State<TabAnimation> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  GlobalKey<__TabState> keyA = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey<__TabState> keyB = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey<__TabState> keyC = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      print("-------");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        accentColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("${Icons.animation}"),
            bottom: new PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size(double.infinity, 48.0),
              child: new Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: new TabBar(
                  onTap: (int value) {
                    print("adfadf $value");
                    keyA.currentState.setAnimation(value == 0); //调用子控件方法
                    keyB.currentState.setAnimation(value == 1); //调用子控件方法
                    keyC.currentState.setAnimation(value == 2); //调用子控件方法
                  },
                  labelColor: Colors.black87,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: <Widget>[
                    Tab(
                        child: new _Tab(
                      0,
                      "Tab1",
                      _tabController,
                      key: keyA,
                    )),
                    Tab(
                        child: new _Tab(
                      1,
                      "Tab2",
                      _tabController,
                      key: keyB,
                    )),
                    Tab(
                        child: new _Tab(
                      2,
                      "Tab3",
                      _tabController,
                      key: keyC,
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(child: Center(child: new Text("1"))),
              new Container(child: Center(child: new Text("2"))),
              new Container(child: Center(child: new Text("3"))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Tab extends StatefulWidget {
  final int tabindex;
  final String tabname;
  final TabController tabcontroller;

  _Tab(this.tabindex, this.tabname, this.tabcontroller, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  __TabState createState() => __TabState();
}

class __TabState extends State<_Tab> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int count;
  bool isSelected;
  Animation<Color> animation;
  AnimationController _conrtoller; // = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), vsync: this);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _conrtoller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), vsync: this);
    ;
    isSelected = widget.tabindex == 0;
    setAnimation(widget.tabindex == 0);
  }

  setAnimation(bool selected) {
    if (isSelected == selected) {
      return;
    }
    isSelected = selected;
    print("widget index ${widget.tabindex} selectedc: $selected");
    _conrtoller?.dispose();
    _conrtoller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), vsync: this);
    animation = ColorTween(
      begin: selected ? Colors.black26 : new Color(0xff622F74),
      end: selected ? new Color(0xff622F74) : Colors.black26,
    ).animate(_conrtoller)
      ..addListener(() {
        print("set stats");
        setState(() {});
      });
    _conrtoller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build${widget.tabindex}");
    return new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(widget.tabname),
        new Container(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 22.0, minWidth: 22.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
          child: new Text(
            widget.tabindex.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 10.0),
          ),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: animation == null ? Colors.black26 : animation.value,
              border: new Border.all(
                width: 0.8,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              boxShadow: [
                new BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                ),
              ]),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```